# I used Swiftify to convert some Obj C code to Swift and got errors that I don't know how to deal with

Tags: objective-c, swift

This is a section of the code that was translated:

Objective C:

```
[SPTRequest userInformationForUserInSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTUser *user) {
        if (error != nil) {
            UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Getting User Info Failed"
                                                           message:error.userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [view show];
            return;
        }
```

Swift:

```
1    SPTRequest.userInformationForUserInSession(session, callback: {(error: NSError, user: SPTUser) -> Void in
2        if error != nil {
3           var view: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Getting User Info Failed", message: error.userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey], delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "")
4            view.show()
5           return
6        }
```

Errors:

1: `Cannot convert value of type '(NSError, SPTUser) -> Void' to expected argument type 'SPTRequestCallback!'`

2: `Value of type 'NSError' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed`

3: `Cannot subscript a value of the type '[NSObject: AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'`

What I'm most confused about is how Objective C would work but the Swift translation doesn't. My bridging header is set up right as well.

Thanks!

Comment: The error messages seem very clear. The first two are all about Optionals and are easily fixed.

Comment: @matt I tried putting them as optionals and I still get the same errors.

Comment: @matt So insert an Optional after `callback?: ...` or `...return}?`

Comment: I provided working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should look something like:

```
SPTRequest.userInformationForUserInSession(session) { error, user in
    guard error == nil else {
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Getting User Info Failed", message: error!.localizedDescription, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "")
        alert.show()
        return
    }

    // carry on
}
```

A few observations:

1. Don't bother specifying types for the `error` and `user` types, and let it infer that for you.
2. I also used trailing closure syntax which eliminates the need for the `callback` parameter.
3. I'd also use `guard` to check for error conditions.
4. I'd use `error.localizedDescription` rather than trying to get it out of the `userDict`. It's easier and more intuitive.

As an aside, nowadays we'd use `UIAlertController` rather than `UIAlertView`. Furthermore, and more significantly, the whole `userInformationForUserInSession` appears to be deprecated, so I'm not sure you should be using this method at all.

Comment: Correct. _Everything_ he's doing is a bad idea. (Not to mention this API is in beta and can't do IPv6 so it can't be used in a shipping app anyway.) Thanks for being the heavy and pointing that out so I don't have to.

Comment: @matt thank you all. Sorry I am new to Swift and trying to help a friend with a summer project. I've seen other apps use this SDK and ship, I'm confused as to why this wouldn't ship.

Answer (score 5):

Don't translate slavishly or mechanically. Think about how the code *works*. In order for `error` to be `nil`, in Swift, it would need to be an Optional. But in your code, it is *not* an Optional. You need to type `error` as `NSError?`, not as `NSError`.

I'm betting that in addition, if there is an error, the SPTUser `user` will be `nil`. But you have not allowed for that either. You need to type this as an `SPTUser?`, not an `SPTUser`.

(You might have to use exclamation marks instead of question marks here; it all depends on how the original API is marked up. But try it first with question marks.)

You may also be running into trouble because the API types `user` as an `id`, that is to say an AnyObject.

The best way to get started, I think, is to let Swift type inference work for you. This compiles fine for me:

```
    SPTRequest.userInformationForUserInSession(session) { 
        (error, user) -> Void in
        //
    }
```

In this way, `error` is an `NSError!` and `user` is an `AnyObject!`, *automatically*. Now, of course, you will need to cast `user` down to an SPTUser, but you can cross that bridge when you come to it.

Comment: I tried both `NSError?` and `NSError!`. And also `SPTUser?` and `SPTUser!`, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly. However, I still get my third error.